# how to hide imported files in my angularjs app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, import

At the top of index html in the head section there're perhaps 50 files defined there for import.  .... 
Is there a way to prevent those imports statements from showing on the client's side?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bundler like [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)